# Slice pandas dataframe column into multiple columns using substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

dataframe 'df' has the following data -

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Item_ID1 | Information - information for item that has ID as 1\nPrice - $7.99\nPlace - Albany, NY |
| Item_ID2 | Information - item's information with ID as 2\nPrice - $5.99\nPlace - Ottawa, ON |

How to segregate the values from column B using 'Information', 'Price', and 'Place' into different columns like -

| Column A | Information | Price | Place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item_ID1 | information for item that has ID as 1 | $7.99 | Albany, NY |
| Item_ID2 | item's information with ID as 2 | $5.99 | Ottawa, ON |

I tried splitting the column B based on string values like 'Information - ', 'Price - ', 'Place - ' but that is becoming more complicated and the very first slice has information on Price and Place which is not required in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by using [**`pandas.Series.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
df[["Information", "Price", "Place"]]= df.pop("Column B").str.split(r"\\n", expand=True)

df= df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace(x.name, "", regex=True).str.strip(" - "))
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df.to_string())

   Column A                            Information  Price       Place
0  Item_ID1  information for item that has ID as 1  $7.99  Albany, NY
1  Item_ID2        item's information with ID as 2  $5.99  Ottawa, ON
```

Answer (score 2):

For a generic method in which you do not need to know the future columns in advance, you can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = df.drop(columns='Column B').join(
 df['Column B']
 .str.extractall(r'([^-]+) - ([^\n]+)\n?')
 .droplevel('match')
 .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
)
```

*NB. I am assuming that you have real newlines, if you have instead the two characters `\` and `n`, you can convert with `df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].str.replace(r'\\n', '\n')`*

Output:

```
   Column A                            Information       Place  Price
0  Item_ID1  information for item that has ID as 1  Albany, NY  $7.99
1  Item_ID2        item's information with ID as 2  Ottawa, ON  $5.99
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on the following ideas:

1. Split `Column B` by `\s-\s|\\n`, using [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).
2. Reshape the result, using [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).
3. Apply [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
(pd.concat([df['Column A'], pd.DataFrame(
    df['Column B'].str.split(r'\s-\s|\\n', expand=True, regex=True).values
    .reshape((-1,2)))
 .pivot_table(columns=0, values=1, aggfunc=list)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.explode(d.columns.tolist(), ignore_index=True))], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   Column A                            Information       Place  Price
0  Item_ID1  information for item that has ID as 1  Albany, NY  $7.99
1  Item_ID2        item's information with ID as 2  Ottawa, ON  $5.99
```